# Is there a way to convert docx to pdf without having word installed in python?

Tags: python, libraries

My computer I'm running the script on doesn't have MS office. Is there a way to convert them without it?

Answer (score 2):

The [PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/PDF) has super useful help pages and [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) also works.

If you install LibreOffice, you just need this code:

```
from subprocess import  Popen
LIBRE_OFFICE = r"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe"

def convert_to_pdf(input_docx, out_folder):
    p = Popen([LIBRE_OFFICE, '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir',
               out_folder, input_docx])
    print([LIBRE_OFFICE, '--convert-to', 'pdf', input_docx])
    p.communicate()


sample_doc = 'file.docx'
out_folder = 'some_folder'
convert_to_pdf(sample_doc, out_folder)
```

Comment: On PythonAnywhere path to LibreOffice is `/usr/bin/soffice` not `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe`